# PL SQL Procedure warning compiled Error PLS-00103

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error, plsqldeveloper

I'm starting with PL/SQL, this is my first Procedure and I find it difficult to compile;  I have tried so many different versions, I carry the last attempt. I don't understand why SQLDEVELOPER say me: "procedure compiled (with errors)".

The compiler say me:" Errore(10,1): PLS-00103: Trovato il simbolo  (find) "DECLARE" instead:  begin    function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor    delete exists prior "

If there are other errors (also logical) please tell me. I would like to improve.

Thank you all for the answers

My Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE calcola_giorn (giornata IN INTEGER) is
  -- si tenga presente che in realtà giornata=idPartita
somma NUMBER;
idcal NUMBER;
nometorn VARCHAR2;
idformaz NUMBER;
nomesquadr VARCHAR2;

DECLARE; 

SELECT idcalendario INTO idcal FROM partita WHERE id= giornata;

SELECT nometorneo INTO nometorn FROM calendario WHERE id= idcal;

CURSOR formazioni_di_giornata IS
    SELECT id, nomesquadra FROM formazione where idpartita= giornata;

CURSOR giocatori_di_giornata IS
    SELECT votogiocatore FROM schiera WHERE idformazione= idformaz;


Begin
OPEN formazioni_di_giornata; 
    FOR tupla_formazione IN formazioni_di_giornata LOOP
      somma:=0;
      FETCH formazioni_di_giornata INTO idformaz, nomesquadr;
        OPEN giocatori_di_giornata;
            FOR tupla_giocatore IN giocatori_di_giornata LOOP
              somma:= somma + tupla_giocatore.votogiocatore;
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE giocatori_di_giornata;
      UPDATE partecipa SET punti= somma WHERE ( (nomesquadra= nomesquadr) AND (nometorneo= nometorn));
      END LOOP;
CLOSE formazioni_di_giornata;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END calcola_giorn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Varchar limit should be defined, like varchar2(100)
2. Replace DECLARE;  with BEGIN
3. All your cursors should go before BEGIN
4. Put END; for the procedure

You can try compiling after making these changes.